# Доступ к объекту в service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Есть html страница, к ней подключен скрипт, из которого можно получить доступ к объекту (например: `object`). В файле index.js есть доступ к этому объекту. Есть функция, которая обращается к `object` и возвращает какие-то данные:

```
const getObject = () => {
  let data = object.data;
  return data;
}
```

При вызове этой функции в файле index.js все работает. Также, к странице подключен service worker. Вот фрагмент кода из него:

```
self.addEventListner('message', event => {
  console.log('message' + event.data);
  importScripts('index.js');
  let data = getObject();
  console.log(data);
}
```

При вызове функции `getObject` в service worker'e вылетает ошибка: `Uncaught ReferenceError: object is not defined at self.addEventListener (sw.js:33)`. Вопрос заключается  в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы был доступ к `object` в service worker'е ?

Comment: передать его в `event.data`?

Comment: пробовал, все равно вылетает ошибка

Comment: а откуда у вас вообще функция `getObject` берет `object`?

Comment: object доступен из скрипта, подключенного к странице